# Ubuntu 17.10 with Gitlab and Nginx (ha!)

Tags: server, 17.10, nginx, gitlab

Gitlab installation worked straight away but "they" want this server to also serve other webpages (wiki and other stuff) so I had to unbundle nginx from Gitlab and do a full installation.

From what I've seen here (https://www.linode.com/docs/development/version-control/how-to-unbundle-nginx-from-omnibus-gitlab-for-serving-multiple-websites) I need passenger installed but, oh surprise, look what happens if you try to:

```
apt-get install nginx-common
{..}
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libnginx-mod-http-passenger : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.10.3-1ubuntu3.1) but 1.12.1-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So basically it doesn't finish passenger installation and I cannot continue :S

Any brilliant ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So, if anyone gets there:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-extras
sudo apt-get install nginx-common 
sudo apt-get install passenger
```

And there you go. Hope it helps.